# Where can I watch Hentai Ouji to Warawanai Neko.: Henneko BBS?

Tags: hentai-ouji-to-warawanai-neko

As the title suggests, I'm looking for the episodes of Hentai Ouji to Warawanai Neko.: Henneko BBS. I've been searching for a while now and can't seem to find anything regarding it, I only find the TV series (which i've already watched). So my question is:

**Is it possible to watch Hentai Ouji to Warawanai Neko.: Henneko BBS online and when yes, where can I find it?**

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hentai Ouji to Warawanai Neko is licenced by Sentai Filmworks according wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_%22Hentai%22_Prince_and_the_Stony_Cat.

If you go on the official website of Sentai Filmworks you will find the blu-ray here : https://shop.sentaifilmworks.com/products/the-hentai-prince-the-stony-cat-complete-collection

It is written :

> Extras: Clean Opening Animation; Clean Closing Animation; BBS Shorts
>   (x12)

The BBS shorts are included. So you just have to buy the blu-ray.